# On a homological finiteness condition

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fundamental-group

Assumption: $X$ is a connected CW complex, and $H_{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z})=\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} H_n (X; \mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated.

Question: does there exist a finite CW complex $Y$ and a map $f:Y \to X$ inducing an isomorphism in integral homology?

Remarks:

1. The answer is almost trivially ''yes'' if $\pi_1 (X)=1$.
2. P. Vogel gave a positive answer to my question (''Un Theoreme de Hurewicz homologique'') if $H_1 (X; \mathbb{Z})=0$ and if $\pi_1 (X)$ satisfies an additional finiteness hypothesis (it has to be ''locally perfect'', i.e. each element is contained in a finitely generated perfect subgroup; a stronger condition that being perfect).
3. I am happy about a positive answer even under the restrictive assumption $H_1 (X; \mathbb{Z})=0$.
4. By the Kan-Thurston theorem, one might assume that $X=BG$ for a discrete group.
5. It is easy to produce an $f:Y \to X$, $Y$ finite, such that $f$ is surjective in homology: $X$ is the union of all its finite subcomplexes, and each homology class of $X$ is supported on one of them. Take a finite generating system for $H_{\ast}(X)$, pick a finite subcomplex for each generator, and take the union of these subcomplexes. It is also no big deal to achieve, by attaching cells to $X$, that $f$ is injective on $H_0$ <strike>and $H_1$ as well</strike>.

EDIT: the last part of the last sentence is wrong; thus I deleted my answer.

Comment: You might want to look at Wall's work http://math.uchicago.edu/~shmuel/tom-readings/wall%20finiteness%201.pdf

Comment: This was my first idea, but I did not find anything that is really close to what i am looking for.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Wall's finiteness obstruction only applies to finitely dominated spaces, no?

Comment: yes: in order to apply Walls theory, one needs a finite domination and in particular finitely presented fundamental group. Moreover, I do seek for a homology isomorphism, not a homotopy equivalence; and I have no control on the groups, so no chance to rule out the finiteness obstruction. I think it is really a different problem.

Comment: @JohannesEbert This is a really cool (and I suspect hard) question: does it make things easier to assume that $X$ is simplicial or at least regular as a CW complex and then look for simplicial or cellular maps?

Comment: @Vidit: you can assume that $X$ is a simplicial complex, but I do not think this makes it much easier.

Comment: You best bet might be to look at Vogel's proof and see if it can be improved. Morally speaking, in the case $H_1(X)=0$ the most natural construction should kill the fundamental group. (I can explain why.) Since you are going to kill the fundamental group anyhow, its local properties should not matter.

Comment: @Misha: my gut feeling is that I should not try to kill $\pi_1$. If $X$ is aspherical, I cannot have a simply connected $Y$ with the desired properties. ''I can explain why'': it would be welcome if you share your insight -:))

Comment: Any finite CW-complex has an acyclic map to the classifying space of a duality group. If what you ask is true, then finite generation is the only known restriction on homology of duality groups. How is this possible?

Comment: @Igor: I guess you mean that for each finite CW, there is a duality group and a map $BG \to X$ (not $X \to BG$). It is fairly easy to produce, for each finite sequence of finite abelian groups, a finite complex that has the sequence of groups as homology: take a wedge of suitable Moore spaces. So: if what you say is true, then any finite sequence of finitely generated abelian groups is the homology of a duality group.

Comment: @Johannes, you are right the map goes the other way, and being duality does not help. The result I mentioned is tue to Hausmann, see an improved version here  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1872.pdf.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry I misread the question. Please ignore the comment

Comment: When $H_1(Y)=0$ by http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2554 and your 1. you can get a zig-zag $X\rightarrow X'\leftarrow Y$ with $Y$ finite and both maps inducing isomorhpishms in homology.

Comment: @MichałKukieła, that can also be achieved by using just the classical Quillen +-construction. One can actually get a homology equivalence $X\rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is simply connected and finite (I'm assuming $H_1(X,\mathbb Z)=0$). I guess Johannes problem is precisely the direction of the arrow.

Comment: @Fernando, Michal: yes, the problem is the direction of the arrow. But the paper you linked to seems very interesting.